# Sharing a cold flow of MutableStateFlow in ViewModel between two fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, viewmodel, kotlin-flow

I've got a problem with a MutableStateFlow property shared between two fragments.

To make it understandable:

I have a `BasicViewModel` which should be always one instance for both of the fragments because of the nav graph implementation

```
private val basicViewModel: basicViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.basic_graph) { defaultViewModelProviderFactory }
```

This ViewModel have a `MutableStateFlow` property declared like this

```
    private val _basicProperty = MutableStateFlow<BasicClass?>(null)
    val basicProperty : Flow<BasicClass?> = _basicId
        .filterNotNull()
        .flatMapConcat { someRepository.getBasicProperty(it) }
        .onEach { _basicProperty.value = it }
        .catch {  }
```

Then, I have `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` declared in navigation using nav graphs which calls the property similarly, like this

```
        basicViewModel.basicProperty
        .filterNotNull()
        .mapNotNull { it.innerProperty}
        .onEach { doSomething(it) }
        .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
```

It all looks fine, but when I navigate to `FragmentA` the flow of BasicProperty loads (data loads from WebApi) then, I navigate to `FragmentB` **and the flow loads again instead of calling already loaded data** which in App it looks kinda lagging because of the **reload**

Question: What should I do/change to get the already existing data from `BasicViewModel` in `FragmentB`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `_basicProperty` is a hot StateFlow, but you never use it for collecting anything. The property you have exposed, `basicProperty`, is a cold flow, so each subscriber that collects it will start a new run of the cold flow. Each of these cold flows will be posting their updates to the MutableStateFlow, so at that point, its state is unpredictable because it's showing the latest thing any collector of the shared cold flow is doing.

I think what you want is for there to be one flow of execution that's shared. So you should have a single StateFlow that is performing the connection, like this:

```
val basicProperty : StateFlow<BasicClass?> = _basicId
    .filterNotNull()
    .flatMapConcat { someRepository.getBasicProperty(it) }
    .catch {  }
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, null)
```

Your original code doesn't do anything to start the flow until each Fragment comes along to collect it. But this code's call to `stateIn` starts the flow a single time in the `viewModelScope` (in this case immediately because of the `Eagerly` parameter).

Now this flow only runs once. You can still have each Fragment run its own downstream flow like you were already doing.

Comment: That is exacly what I needed. Thanks @Tenfour04 for the answer and great explanation. It seems that I have to read some more about flows in Kotlin. Thanks!